# table adapter returning incorrect results

Tags: c#, linq, tableadapter

I have an application which takes in a csv file and returns certain rows .

The code that takes the csv and tells which data to send to the db is shown here

```
       List<string[]> Results = sm.parseCSV2(ofd.FileName, de).Where(x=>x.Length >5).ToList();


                    foreach (string[] item2 in Results)
                    {
                        objSqlCommands.sqlCommandInsertorUpdate2("INSERT", Results);//laClient[0]);
                    }
```

with my parsing code here

```
    public List<string[]> parseCSV2(string path, char[] delim)
    {
        // Intialise return value    
        List<string[]> parsedData = new List<string[]>();

        try
        {
            // With 'StreamRader' read file that is located in save pat    
            using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                string line; // current line
                string[] row; // array row

                // Go thru file until we reach the end
                while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    row = line.Split(delim);// arry row equals values delimited by pipe


                        parsedData.Add(row); // add this to return value <List>


                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }

        return parsedData; // return list 
    }
```

alongside my sql code

```
          objConnections.executeSQL(connection,
                                           "INSERT INTO generic.Client(ClientName) VALUES('" + text + "')");
```

I am then calling the tableadapter

```
      //Refreshs the Client table on display from the 
                        this.clientTableAdapter.Fill(this.CalcDataSet.Client);

                    //update the view 
                    dgvClientlst.Update() ;
```

However the data being returned is  shown below

```
                System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String[]]
```

I have had it suggested that my query is actually printing the list ToString() but as my code isnt doing that I'm unsure what the problem is . Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 foreach (string[] item2 in Results)
     {
          objSqlCommands.sqlCommandInsertorUpdate2("INSERT", item2);//You were mixed up with Results here
     }
```

I think your code might be this (I'm not sure if your `objSqlCommands.sqlCommandInsertorUpdate2` can handle a `string[]` passed in?)

```
 foreach (string[] item2 in Results)
     {
         foreach(string item in item2)
           objSqlCommands.sqlCommandInsertorUpdate2("INSERT", item);
     }
```

Comment: I changed my code to yours but the returned values is still wrong

Comment: the same problem as before its printing out the System. etc rather than the values

Comment: @KingKong , sorry should have done that , at the moment its now printing System.String[]

Comment: @user2546071 all your problem is in this `objSqlCommands.sqlCommandInsertorUpdate2` method, I don't know what it does to your database, it looks like that it converts any thing passed in as the second parameter to `string`, hence an array of string will make it output `System.String[]`.

Comment: @KingKong   insertOrUpdate2 runs like this 
                    objConnections.executeSQL(connection,
                                               "INSERT INTO generic.Client(ClientName) VALUES('" + text + "')"); ..... is there a better way to pass the data which will give proper results instead of system.String[] ?

Comment: @KingKong , tried the second part and that worked its now printing correctly thanks